# zsh: command not found: cwd can't seem to use Python in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, installation, google-cloud-sdk

Firstly, **please answer in layman's terms**. I have looked at what feels like hundreds of articles and I have no idea what people are talking about (what is zsh, bash, PATH, all this terminology). All I want is to use Python and install packages so I can use Google Cloud SDK (I am familiar with BigQuery in the UI). I'm so confused by all this Python set up!

Yesterday I successfully downloaded Python, and even managed to somehow install Google Cloud SDK using a few Youtube Tutorials and started using it with BigQuery. Now I don't know what I pressed, but today I open Terminal and **none of my code runs!** I see this error message: [/Users/username/.zshrc:7: command not found: “alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3LwG.png)

Even a simple 'cwd' doesn't work...
[zsh: command not found: cwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy56X.png)

Can someone please help and explain what exactly I'm supposed to be doing? Imagine you're explaining it to your grandma please thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have enabled Python in the terminal. To start using Python in the terminal, you need to open Terminal and just type `python`. You must do this each time you open Terminal, otherwise Python will not be running.

Comment: When I type 'python', it says zsh: command not found: python

Comment: Try reinstalling Python